# How to import to packages android.R and myapp.R without conflicts?

Tags: java, android

I'm completely new to java, I need to import both:

```
import com.myapp.R;
import android.R
```

at the same time sine I need to use translations from my strings.xml folder and also the the icon `R.drawable.ic_media_play`. However I get an error due to imports collisions.

How can I access resources both from android and my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't import both. The convention is to import your project's R file (com.myapp.R), and to use full package notation when using the android R file. This way, it's easy to tell when your referencing your own identifiers, and when you're referencing an external identifier.

So if you wanted to reference the `ic_media_play` identifer, you'd use `android.R.drawable.ic_media_play`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import them both.  Refer to them by their fully qualified names.

import android.R

...

doSomething(R.drawable.ic_media_play)

is equivalent to

...

doSomething(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play)

You can import the one that you use most, and use a fully qualified name for the other